# DolphinDB: NULL values are returned after the record is updated

Tags: sql-update, dolphindb

I want to update the bar “09:31m” by adding each of the previous value in bar “09:30m” to each field in bar “09:31m”. My script is as follows:

```
update order_sum_all set b_sum = b_sum + prev(b_sum), s_sum = s_sum + prev(s_sum), b_item_sum = b_item_sum + prev(b_item_sum), s_item_sum = prev(s_item_sum) where TimeStamp = 09:31m or TimeStamp = 13:01m context by WindCode;
```

[image]

However, all of the results in this bar are NULL values. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `where` clause is executed before the `prev` function. According to the `where` condition you specified, there is only one bar of data filtered out (09:31m) and its previous values are NULL (because 09:30m is not included). So the results are NULL values. For more details, see [Order of Execution](https://dolphindb.com/help/SQLStatements/orderOfExecute.html).

The `case when` statement is supported since version 1.30.21/2.00.9. You can try the following script:

```
time = 09:00m + 1..60
b_sum = 1..60
t = table(time, b_sum)
update t set b_sum = (case when time == 09:31m then  b_sum + prev(b_sum) else b_sum end)
```

If you use the previous version, calculate the new values first and then update the bar “09:31m”.